# Does a bounded sequence in $L^{1}(\Omega)$ converge to a limit in the sense of distributions?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, weak-convergence

Suppose $\{f_{n}\}_{n \ge 1} \subset L^{1}(\Omega)$ is a uniformly bounded sequence and $\Omega = (0,1)$. Can we say that $f_{n}$ converges in $\mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$ (up to a subsequence) to a limit $f$?

My thoughts:

We can embed $L^{1}(\Omega)$ into the space $\mathcal{M}_{b}(\Omega)$ of finite measures. Since $\mathcal{M}_{b}(\Omega)$ is the dual space of $C_{b}(\Omega)$ and $f_{n}$ is also bounded in $\mathcal{M}_{b}(\Omega)$ we have that (up to a subsequence) $f_{n}$ converges weak-* to a limit $f$ in $\mathcal{M}_{b}(\Omega)$. Now $f$ being a measure induces a distribution via the mapping
$$ \phi \mapsto \int_{\Omega}\phi ~df. $$
But I am not sure if this argument will imply convergence in $\mathcal{D}'$. Sure the limit is a distribution but I am not sure if the convergence will actually take place in the distributional sense. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: A sequence $f_n$ of distributions converges if and only if it converges in the weak-* topology, i.e. if and only if $\langle f_n, \phi \rangle \to \langle f, \phi \rangle$ holds for all $\phi \in \mathcal{D}(\Omega)$. It seems to me that your conclusion that $\langle f_n, \phi \rangle \to \langle f_n, \phi \rangle$ for all $\phi$ in the larger set  $C_b(\Omega)$ implies this. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: $f_{n}$ converges weak-* to a limit $f$ in $\mathcal{M}_{b}(\Omega)$? This is wrong.

Comment: @geetha290krm Really? because it is the same argument used here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1627579/852108 isn't it?

Comment: You cannot just omit the word 'subsequence' from that answer.  Even in the real line a bounded sequence need not be convergent. Please pay some attention to rigor.

Comment: @geetha290krm i mentioned up to a subsequence in the opening of my question. i assumed that much would be clear.

Comment: Under 'My thoughts', in the secodn line you wrote a wrong statement and I am just pointing that out. Every statement you write has to be correct. Just because you talked about subsequence in the beginning you cannot omit it later. Please correct the error. instead of arguing.